# To make the russians and greeks authors' surnames in small caps in biblatex

Tags: biblatex, footnotes, small-caps

I'm writing a bachelor in French and when I cited books in Russian and Greek the authors' surnames wasn't displayed in footnotes and in bibliography in  small caps, in the same text there are no such problems with surnames in Latin characters.

I tried to add this code in preamble:

```
...
\newfontfamily\greekfont[Script=Greek,Mapping=tex-text]{CMU Serif}
\newfontfamily\russianfont[Script=Cyrillic,Mapping=tex-text]{CMU Serif}
...
```

and in bibliography entries like this:

```
@Book{AlKarapan,
author = {{Α}λέξανδρος Κ. \textgreek{Καραπαναγοπούλου}},
title = {Η Μεγάλη Σύνοδος της Ορθοδόξου Ανατολικής Εκκλησίας},
publisher = {auto-édition},
year = {\hbox{1990--1998}},
volumes = {6},
address = {Αθήνα}
}

@Inbook{CypinIstorijaRPC,
author = {{В}ладислав \textrussian{Цыпин}},
title = {История Русской Церкви 1917--1997},
chapter = {VIII},
publisher = {Издательство Спасо-Преображенского Валаамского монастыря},
address = {Москва},
date = {1997},
urldate = {2010-10-25},
url = {http://old.pravoslavie.by/podpod.asp?id=135&Session=10}
}
```

And I've got this:
[image: in footnotes]
[image: in the bibliography]
 I don't know if it's right technically but it works for me.

Does anybody have better ideas? All improvements and innovations ARE WELCOMED. :)))

Comment: Why exactly are you not satisfied with your current solution?

Comment: I'm satisfied, the only thing that I'm worrying is the level of the technical details. Maybe more perfect solution exists? :)

Comment: Oh, sorry, I didn't notice you had to edit your bibliography as well. Perhaps having a look at siam.bst can help you: it outputs author names in smallcaps, but you don't have to change your .bib files for that. I never tried to use it with Greek or Russian names however.

Comment: Ideally you'd have to enclose all Greek and Russian text in `\text…` commands or the equivalent environments in order to get consistent font settings and hyphenation.

Comment: Yes, I do it in the main text, but I don't need the names in small-caps just surnames.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With biblatex, you can change appearance of a surname by redefining command \mkbibnamelast.

```
\renewcommand\mkbibnamelast[1]{\textsc{#1}}
```

Complete example for xelatex:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{french}
\setotherlanguages{czech,greek,russian}
\usepackage[style=authoryear,babel=other,backend=biber]{biblatex}

\usepackage{fontspec}

\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text]{CMU Serif}
\renewcommand\mkbibnamelast[1]{\textsc{#1}}

\bibliography{test}
\newfontfamily\greekfont[Script=Greek,Mapping=tex-text]{CMU Serif}
\newfontfamily\russianfont[Script=Cyrillic,Mapping=tex-text]{CMU Serif}

\begin{document}
Example one\footfullcite{AlKarapan}, example two\footfullcite{CypinIstorijaRPC} and latin surname\footfullcite{ooo}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

and bib file:

```
@Book{AlKarapan,
author = {Καραπαναγοπούλου, Αλέξανδρος Κ.},
title = {Η Μεγάλη Σύνοδος της Ορθοδόξου Ανατολικής Εκκλησίας},
publisher = {auto-édition},
year = {\hbox{1990--1998}},
volumes = {6},
address = {Αθήνα},
hyphenation={greek}
}

@Inbook{CypinIstorijaRPC,
author = {Владислав Цыпин},
title = {История Русской Церкви 1917--1997},
chapter = {VIII},
publisher = {Издательство Спасо-Преображенского Валаамского монастыря},
address = {Москва},
date = {1997},
urldate = {2010-10-25},
url = {http://old.pravoslavie.by/podpod.asp?id=135&Session=10},
hyphenation={russian}
}
@Inbook{ooo,
author = {Petr Nikl},
title = {Nějaký titulek},
chapter = {VIII},
publisher = {Academia},
address = {Praha},
date = {1997},
hyphenation={czech}
}
```

Result:
[image]
[image]

Comment: I have no idea why, but somehow there is no space between Αλέξανδρος and K.

Comment: Thank you very much Michal. 
But when try to compile your exemple, bibtex gives me the errors:
  This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (TeX Live 2010)
  The top-level auxiliary file: test1.aux
  I found no \citation commands---while reading file test1.aux
   I found no \bibdata command---while reading file test1.aux
   I found no \bibstyle command---while reading file test1.aux
   (There were 3 error messages)
What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: @Caramdir: it was because I used biber for biblatex 1.3, but my biblatex package was v1.2. after biblatex update, it's ok now.

Comment: @filokalos: it is better to use biber instead of bibtex to translate your bibliography, because bibtex has no support for utf-8 encoding. biber is relatively new program, so if you don't have it installed, you can install it with tlmgr utility. if you want to use bibtex, you can change "backend=biber" to "backend=bibtex"

Comment: @michal.h21
It works!!!!!! Great!!! THANK YOU! Great job!

Comment: Unfortunately it not working with font Linux Libertine, but for CMU Serif it's awesome!